# Abusing Query or QueryAsync when used with CUD operations

Tags: dapper

I'm trying to implement a repository with Dapper as ORM, I want inserted or updated entities to be returned back. This is what I came up with, it works just fine but I'm wondering if this is abusing the default Query and QueryAsync methods?

```
public async Task<Models.TestTable> Insert(Models.TestTable inputObject)
{
    IEnumerable<Models.TestTable> output;

    output = await _connection.QueryAsync<Models.TestTable>(
        sql: string.Format("INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)"),
        param: inputObject);

    return output.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only actual *problem* I can see there is the unnecessary `string.Format`.

Personally I *might* have been tempted to just update the `Id` (or whatever) in the existing object, but your `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` works fine too. I *might* be very tempted to move the local declaration inline via `var output = ...`, and of course once I've done *that* it makes it tempting to make the entire thing inline:

```
public async Task<Models.TestTable> Insert(Models.TestTable inputObject)
    => (await _connection.QueryAsync<Models.TestTable>(
    "INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)",
    inputObject)).SingleOrDefault();
```

but most of that is trivia and subjective. Heck, even the `string.Format` is just *unnecessary* rather than *problematic*.

One other thing to check: did we (and I can't remember!) add a `QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync` method? I know we added `QuerySingleOrDefault` - I just can't remember about the `*Async` twin.

Comment: Yes, the string.Format is there (by mistake) because it's supposed to be like this: "INSERT INTO {0} (FirstName, LastName)...". I just checked and yes, you did implement QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync, which I didn't pay enough attention and missed it. Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: @Iztoksson if you're injecting the table name, just be sure to white-list it (i.e. check that it is a valid and expected table name - don't allow unexpected values)